# Why are these children as array not rendered in TS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I have a dead simple component. Works perfectly in javascript.

```
const Test = (props: any) => <div>{props.children}</div>;

const Root: React.SFC<{}> = props => {
  return (
    <div className="Root">
      <h1>hello world.</h1>
      <Test>{[...Array(20)].map((_, index) => <h1>test{index}</h1>)}</Test>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

But doesn't work in typescript. Why?

Both use same React version.

EDIT:

TypeScript:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKGoWo

JavaScript:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGMLOv

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry, typo. Edited to [...Array(20)], still same problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought so too, but check the codepens.

Comment: FYI [bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - Nice one!

Comment: This was a fascinating question to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you change it from that spread array map to

```
<Test>{Array.from({length:20}, (_, index) => <h1 key={index}>test{index}</h1>)}</Test>
```

(I also added `key` to that, since React complains once it starts working. :-) )

Not working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYeQzv?editors=1010

Working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKGoya?editors=1010

It has to do with how TypeScript transpiles that spread notation. TypeScript is converting that `[...Array(20)].map(/*...*/)` to this:

```
Array(5).slice().map(/*...*/)
```

The problem with that is that `Array(20)` creates an array of length 20 with **no entries in it**. `slice` replicates that. `map` only visits entries that actually exist in the array, not gaps. But `[...Array(20)]` creates an array with 20 entries containing `undefined`, which `map` **will** visit:

```js
const a1 = [...Array(5)];
console.log(0 in a1);   // true
const a1m = a1.map((_, index) => index);
console.log(0 in a1m);  // true
console.log(a1m);       // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

const a2 = Array(5).slice();
console.log(0 in a2);   // false
const a2m = a2.map((_, index) => index);
console.log(0 in a2m);  // false
console.log(a2m);       // (gaps)
```

```html
Look in the real console (the snippet console gives the impression values exist in the array when they don't).
```

[Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) kindly [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887560/why-are-these-children-as-array-not-rendered-in-ts/50887699#comment88776913_50887560) a [bug report for it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856).

Comment: thanks, but this is ridicilous of TypeScript, i can't believe something as simple as a spread operator isn't working as expected.

Comment: @J.Reku - I've figured out why now (see edit), and it's definitely not a faithful emulation of spread. It may be worth having a nose around to see if there's a setting for being pure vs. being fast or something (a couple of Babel plugins have those settings, compromising correctness for performance in a couple of cases). If you don't find such a setting, may be worth reporting as a bug.

Comment: @J.Reku - No need, Yury [found a bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887560/why-are-these-children-as-array-not-rendered-in-ts/50887699#comment88776913_50887560) already there.